# How to save Scroll position in a Scroll view?

Tags: android, position, save, scrollview

I have a very long text in the Scroll view . When user press back button or quit the program,
i want the Scroll view save its position  and then when the activity is recreated, user can continue where they was left. 
 How can i do that?

Comment: Related: [Keep position of ScrollView after back to prev Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26070595/559745)

Answer (score 3):

[getScrollY()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getScrollY%28%29)
describes what you need. ScrollView inherits that and returns scroll position. To restore the position later, you need to call either [scrrollTo(int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29) or [smoothScrollTo(int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#smoothScrollTo%28int,%20int%29). To deal with back button, you need to override [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29).